# Breakpoints in IntelliJ IDEA & Wildfly work only once

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints, wildfly

I've started Wildfly in debug mode and deployed our application.

I've set the breakpoint to a certain line where a log statement is print.

When performing a certain action on the GUI the breakpoint is triggered correctly. But when I perform this action for a second or third time the breakpoint is no longer triggered. Only restarting the server resolves this problem.

All the while the log statement gets printed so it means the method is entered.

Colleagues of mine also do not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reason

1. Many files with same name are loaded ( one gets called once and another any other time)
2. Breakpoint does not work properly when you override a file in different source

To confirm you should try adding different log statements to confirm if correct file is executing and add breakpoint in class (generated source) also.